# How to install the Omnicomple plugin for Gvim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim

I am new to vim; and I can't install the `omnicomplete` plugin.

What I've done so far:

- Downloaded the zip file from vim.org, which contained 3 folders: autoload,after - which contain a ftplugin folder - and doc.
- I have pasted the files directly in the vimfiles folder - which is supposed to have it  working,
- Even tried putting the files inside the corresponding folders in the vim73 folder.
- Checked if the script was loaded using the command :scriptname in vim and it was not listed

What have I missed, done wrong? (Where's an automatic exe based installation when you need it?).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 'set omnifunc' line in your vimrc?  The scripts in autoload are not loaded unless they are referenced, and I don't think your omni script is getting referenced if you haven't set your omnifunc.

See `:h omnifunc` and also take a look at this wiki page:
[wiki page on omnicompletion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion)

Also, I believe any recent version of Vim has Omnicomplete files included in base distribution, so you probably didn't need to install new ones.

Comment: yea, looks like i had it already, i was expecting an autocomplete by default like intellisense i.e myclass."autocomplete activates here". didnt happen; doing more research

Answer (score 0):

Vim 7.3 comes with omnicomplete by default but you need to hit a key combo to get the completions list. There are a bunch of [autocompletion scripts on vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=auto%20completion&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search), my favorite is [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879).